# How to think about a function of random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random, random-functions

Consider the random variables $X, Y$ defined on the probability space $(S, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ taking value respectively in the Borel spaces $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{X}})$, $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{Y}})$.

Consider a measurable function $f:\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Consider $f(X,Y)$.

How should I think about $f(X,Y)$?

(1) $f(X,Y)$ can be thought of as a random variable $W:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $W(s)=f(X(s), Y(s))$.

(2) $f(X,Y)$ can be thought of as a deterministic function $f:\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ assigning $f(x,y)$ to each $(x,y)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$.

(3) Can $f(X,Y)$ be thought as a random function, i.e. as a random variable taking value in a function space?

Comment: Hints: (2) is a description of $f$. Can you find any function space in this context?

Comment: My impression is that there is that $f$ is ONE function and it does not move in a function space...

Comment: So is mine. Btw, only (1) is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Why is (2) wrong? Isn't it just restating what does it mean $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because it is not a description of $f(X,Y)$. As said it is a description of $f$.

Comment: Is $f(X,Y)$ the same as $f$...no. That should address (2) and (3). Think about the objects you are modeling, not how they are generated.

Comment: I see, thank you very much

Comment: But what happens if I do the following: define the random function $G:S\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is the space of all measurable functions from $\mathcal{Y}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that, given $s\in S$, $G(s)(y)=f(X(s), y)\in \mathbb{R}$ for any $y\in \mathcal{Y}$. $G$ is a random function "indexed by values of $X$". Does it make sense? Sorry, I don't know how to be formally correct...

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. For example, if$ G(s) = X(s)y$, then indeed $G(S)$ will generate linear functions of $y$ with random slopes.

Comment: @Bey Regarding my last question, suppose I assume that $Z|X,Y\sim Be (f(X,Y))$, where $Be$ denotes Bernoulli. Now I define the random function $G$ as written above. Can I say that $Z|X,Y\sim Be (f(X,Y))$ is equivalent to $Z|G, Y \sim Be(G(Y))$? Is it obvious or is there any more subtle reason such as equivalence in cardinalities of some  sample spaces? Also if $f$ is Borel measurable, is it also $G(s)$ Borel measurable?

Comment: I think that makes sense if $G$ is defined over the same sample space as $X$ (or, more accurately...$G$,$X$, and $Y$ have some common sample space).

Comment: OK, I have asked this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255134/from-deterministic-functions-to-random-functions Please help if you have some time, thanks

Comment: @STF You have deleted the linked question. Is there still more to be answered here?